# The whole page is not being parsed with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am able to retrieve anything past the first 19 records from my desired website. Given that the listings on the site are dynamic, I believe this may have something to do with only the first 19 being returned when I run my python code. I have done some reading online but have not found a solution to my problem.

Bellow is my my full python code. I would love to get the communities input on what I can do to fix my issue.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv


headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
url = "https://www.producthunt.com/time-travel/2019/1/7"
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 



soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")



name = []
description = []
category = []
up_votes = []


ph_project_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='item_54fdd')



for container in ph_project_div:
    
    ph_name = container.a.find('h3', class_='font_9d927 medium_51d18 semiBold_e201b title_9ddaf lineHeight_042f1 underline_57d3c').text
    name.append(ph_name)

    ph_desc = container.a.find('p', class_='font_9d927 grey_bbe43 small_231df normal_d2e66 tagline_619b7 lineHeight_042f1 underline_57d3c').text
    description.append(ph_desc)
    
    
    ph_cat = container.find('span', class_='font_9d927 grey_bbe43 xSmall_1a46e lineHeight_042f1 underline_57d3c')
    category.append(ph_cat)
    
    ph_vote = container.find('span', class_='font_9d927 small_231df semiBold_e201b lineHeight_042f1 underline_57d3c')
    up_votes.append(ph_vote)
    


phunt = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product Name': name,
    'Product Description': description,
    'Product Category': category,
    'Product Votes': up_votes,
})



phunt.to_csv("ph_01_04_2019.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're correct that javascript is being used to get the next set of posts. This is an example of a scroll event triggering a HTTP request to the server.

To see this, you can use inspect page --> Network tools --> XHR. Clear all the requests and scroll down. You will see a post request being made and at the right hand side you'll see data. I tend to search for something I expect to see to confirm the data is there.

There are two ways to deal with this type of dynamic content.

1. Mimic the HTTP request
2. Use browser activity to grab the data

The first is always the better option and if there's potential for an API point etc.. then it is better to use this. Efficiency and accuracy of the data is important.

The second option relies on packages like selenium which are slower, can be quite brittle to changes in HTML, annoying to code.

To gather the information for the code below, I copy the cURL of the request found in XHR part of network tools. I use a website that converts this into a python format such as curl.trillworks.com.

The HTTP requests may just need a simple get request to the correct url for the endpoint, that is always good to do first before you have to input headers/params/data. In this example, you get all three but actually you only need a user-agent and the type of response object you want along with the data used to direct you towards the correct response.

### Code Example

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'M',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"operationName":"Posts","variables":{"year":2019,"month":1,"day":7,"cursor":"MjA=","includeLayout":false},"query":"query Posts($year: Int, $month: Int, $day: Int, $cursor: String) {\\n posts(first: 20, year: $year, month: $month, day: $day, after: $cursor) {\\n edges {\\n node {\\n id\\n ...PostItemList\\n __typename\\n }\\n __typename\\n }\\n pageInfo {\\n endCursor\\n hasNextPage\\n __typename\\n }\\n __typename\\n }\\n}\\n\\nfragment PostItemList on Post {\\n id\\n ...PostItem\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment PostItem on Post {\\n id\\n _id\\n comments_count\\n name\\n shortened_url\\n slug\\n tagline\\n updated_at\\n ...CollectButton\\n ...PostThumbnail\\n ...PostVoteButton\\n ...TopicFollowButtonList\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment CollectButton on Post {\\n id\\n name\\n isCollected\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment PostThumbnail on Post {\\n id\\n name\\n thumbnail {\\n id\\n media_type\\n ...MediaThumbnail\\n __typename\\n }\\n ...PostStatusIcons\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment MediaThumbnail on Media {\\n id\\n image_uuid\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment PostStatusIcons on Post {\\n name\\n product_state\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment PostVoteButton on Post {\\n _id\\n id\\n featured_at\\n updated_at\\n disabled_when_scheduled\\n has_voted\\n ... on Votable {\\n id\\n votes_count\\n __typename\\n }\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment TopicFollowButtonList on Topicable {\\n id\\n topics {\\n edges {\\n node {\\n id\\n ...TopicFollowButton\\n __typename\\n }\\n __typename\\n }\\n __typename\\n }\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment TopicFollowButton on Topic {\\n id\\n slug\\n name\\n isFollowed\\n ...TopicImage\\n __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment TopicImage on Topic {\\n name\\n image_uuid\\n __typename\\n}\\n"}'
response = requests.post('https://www.producthunt.com/frontend/graphql', headers=headers, data=data)
data = response.json()
for a in response.json()['data']['posts']['edges']:
    name = a['node']['name']
    subtext = a['node']['tagline']
    votes = a['node']['votes_count']
    category = a['node']['topics']['edges'][0]['node']['name']
    print('-'*20)
    print('Name: ',name)
    print('Tagline: ',subtext)
    print('Category: ',category)
    print('Votes: ',votes)
```

### Output

```
--------------------
Name:  Newbook Models
Tagline:  Find & book fashion models online
Category:  Productivity
Votes:  57
--------------------
Name:  3Leaf Edibles - Quinoa Granola Bite
Tagline:  Vegan, low dose, high quality edibles.
Category:  Health and Fitness
Votes:  57
--------------------
Name:  Payfacile
Tagline:  We simplify access to online payment.
Category:  Fintech
Votes:  43
--------------------
Name:  Halo by Motorola
Tagline:  Watch over your baby from above
Category:  Kids
Votes:  27
--------------------
Name:  Bowflex Max Intelligence
Tagline:  Bring the benefits of a personal trainer to your home
Category:  Health and Fitness
Votes:  23
```

### Explanation

The headers, you don't need to specify a `user-agent`, anything will do so I just used a single character. The `content-type` was necessary though, you find this through trial an error.

The data I'm not gonna lie I didnt' have the heart to try break this down, my guess is that alternating it may end not getting you the data you want. One of the nice things about this data, is that you can alter the year/month/day and it will give you the data for that page that requires scrolling to trigger the items.

You hadn't specifically asked about this but using something like f-strings to input specific data per each requests.get() call would be an approach to that.

Now what you get back is a json object, the method `response.json()` converts this object to a python dictionary. So all methods attributed to dictionary can be used.

I strongly recommend you look at the `response.json()` dictionary, you wont really see what the name,subtext means unless you do that. But most json objects are nested datasets and so the data you usually want is behind many keys as in this case. For every post I've looped around to grab the name/taglines.

### Typical output of list item of response.json()['data']['posts']['edges']

```
{'node': {'id': '142398',
  '__typename': 'Post',
  '_id': 'UG9zdC0xNDIzOTg=',
  'comments_count': 9,
  'name': 'dinely',
  'shortened_url': '/r/p/142398',
  'slug': 'dinely',
  'tagline': 'Up to 50% off top restaurants, no coupon needed',
  'updated_at': '2020-04-28T16:55:48-07:00',
  'topics': {'edges': [{'node': {'id': '2',
      '__typename': 'Topic',
      'slug': 'android',
      'name': 'Android',
      'isFollowed': False,
      'image_uuid': 'd3e235c7-437b-4ed1-8298-2ce04eded455'},
     '__typename': 'TopicEdge'},
    {'node': {'id': '8',
      '__typename': 'Topic',
      'slug': 'iphone',
      'name': 'iPhone',
      'isFollowed': False,
      'image_uuid': '0ee71650-973d-4933-a3eb-c7201950db4b'},
     '__typename': 'TopicEdge'},
    {'node': {'id': '159',
      '__typename': 'Topic',
      'slug': 'drinking',
      'name': 'Drinking',
      'isFollowed': False,
      'image_uuid': '33a0c652-253d-491f-b86b-4e9ba32ee203'},
     '__typename': 'TopicEdge'},
    {'node': {'id': '250',
      '__typename': 'Topic',
      'slug': 'travel',
      'name': 'Travel',
      'isFollowed': False,
      'image_uuid': '0a49cae9-ccff-47f1-8998-d0f47c2e7775'},
     '__typename': 'TopicEdge'},
    {'node': {'id': '278',
      '__typename': 'Topic',
      'slug': 'e-commerce',
      'name': 'E-Commerce',
      'isFollowed': False,
      'image_uuid': '1aa939fc-89dd-49ae-9fde-d456f9a6c8d2'},
     '__typename': 'TopicEdge'}],
   '__typename': 'TopicConnection'},
  'featured_at': '2019-01-07T03:52:19-08:00',
  'disabled_when_scheduled': True,
  'has_voted': False,
  'votes_count': 58,
  'thumbnail': {'id': '703734',
   'media_type': 'image',
   '__typename': 'Media',
   'image_uuid': '96893366-45e6-477e-9bb8-0e04c2070da6'},
  'product_state': 'default',
  'isCollected': False},
 '__typename': 'PostEdge'}
```

Comment: Hello Aaron. Thank you for your detailed response. After modifying the date range and running the code you provided, I am not able to return anything even though the script runs successfully. I also tried the number of records outputted as I want to capture all records on each page. That may be another issue all together but I wanted to know when modifying date, do I need to change any of the parameters in the "data =" section?

Comment: I've just changed the 'day' and 'year' values and seems to be outputting the correct items. It only prints the ones that are invoked by javascript, i.e when you scroll and then data appears. Have you copied my code exactly into your editor ?